# Assigning dynamic variables through JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a pet project where I've been creating a functions only JS framework... and wasn't sure if there was any way to simplify the following... in this case Dynamic variable assignment...

```
String.prototype.is = function(x) {window[this]=window[this]||x;}
"a".is(42);
alert(a); // window.alert shows 42
```

Is there any simpler way to do this with functions? This is for the sole purpose of achieving a functions-only framework... so using "a = 42;" is not permitted... I want this to be usable for not just numbers, but strings, arrays, booleans, dates, etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of such construction? `is` actually works as "assign if undefined or empty", but always uses global variables. This construction is very strange, could you clarify the use case?

Comment: Tadeck, as I mentioned I'm creating a javaScript framework which is completely function based. So I could write something like:

"a".is(9);"b".is(10);"c".is(14);alert(average(a,b,c));

I know there are simpler ways to do this... but I'm focusing on creating the framework to be a functions-only one...

Does that clarify things?

Comment: Actually it gives some insight on what drives you to do such thing, but it looks like you are making bad design decisions here. First of all, you are changing global variables, secondly you are altering common types, third the syntax looks weird. The problem here may be, you are trying to write something like your own language (not really a framework), or you are just ignoring the characteristics of JavaScript. See [alcidesqueiroz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12850885/548696) for good insight into that. Even if you decide to continue writing a framework, use his advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem in your idea, it's not a good practice to change the prototype of native types. This can result in an unexpected (and sometimes almost impossible to debug) behavior when using with third-party code.

No problem in your main idea, but I suggest you to wrap the objects you want to manipulate with another under your full control and so decorate these objects with the additional behavior provided by your wrapper. This is the jQuery approach, a lot safer.

Comment: Al, how would I go about wrapping it? I know jQuery, being one of the kings in this sort of thing... but I'd rather not try to dissect it in order to get an understanding of it... are there any links that may show a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: In few words: yourWrapper("a").is(42); You could do like jQuery and create a shorter access point, for jQuery it's $ (a sortcut for "jQuery").

Comment: Another important point: avoid to pollute your global namespace doing things like window[something] = "some value"; This is another bad practice. =D  Here's a link for the slides of a talk I gave about Javascript Antipatterns, I know you maybe don't speak portuguese to understand, but the code you will, I'm sure! =D: http://www.slideshare.net/alcidesqueiroz/antipatterns-javascript-14503235

Comment: Look at this example on how you could create a wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/QWhsz/

Answer (score 0):

You can use new ES 5 getters and setters.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get

Comment: SBR, looks promising... could I see an example of get/set using my function as a base?